# Access denied to file in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am trying to copy an entire directory from one place to other through installer.
Below is the mentioned Code

```
public static void copyDirectory(string Src, string Dst)
{
    String[] Files;

    if (Dst[Dst.Length - 1] != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        Dst += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    if (!Directory.Exists(Dst)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Dst);
    Files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(Src);
    foreach (string Element in Files)
    {
        // Sub directories
        if (Directory.Exists(Element))
            copyDirectory(Element, Dst + Path.GetFileName(Element));
        // Files in directory
        else
            File.Copy(Element, Dst + Path.GetFileName(Element), true);

    }
}
```

It is giving me above error.please help me out in the above mentioned issue.

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Do you just want to know what "Access denied" means? Do you want us to fix it?

Comment: in what scope do you execute this code? ASP.NET? Console-App?

Comment: The processs cannot access  the file 'C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\Setup3\DBSyncUtil.dll because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I am using Console Application. Actually I am using an installer.Firstly it takes Back Up of previous version.Then it installs the new version.If there is any error it needs to restore the previous version application of backup.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure all applications that use that dll are closed.
2. since you are using "installer", but is still c# code, does it use the dll file?

Comment: The applications that use the dll are closed.Since the installer itself adds the exe and required dlls on machine.Secondly, I couldnt get the next point . I mean during installer the C# code uses Dll file? If that is the question then it is yes.I do use the dll while installing in C# code.

Comment: Please help me in the above aspect.

Comment: try using handles.exe from sysinternals to check if the dll is referenced by anything..

Comment: if you run the installer from you main application, the main application may be disappeared from the task manager, but it might be still using the dll file, check with process explorer from sysinternals